# Multiple delete wont work (asp.net vb)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, aspxgridview

code sample aspx vb behind code:

```
Protected Sub btnDelete_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click

    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows

        Dim checkbox As CheckBox = CType(row.FindControl("chkdelete"), CheckBox)

        If checkbox.Checked Then

            Dim ID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys(row.RowIndex).Value)

            SqlDataSource1.DeleteParameters("ID").DefaultValue = ID.ToString()

            SqlDataSource1.Delete()

        End If

    Next row
```

front code :
`

```
         <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkdelete" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="No" 
               SortExpression="ID"/>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" 
               SortExpression="Name"/>
            <asp:CommandField Headertext="Edit" ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:CommandField Headertext="Delete" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
       </Columns>    
   </asp:GridView>
   <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" onclick="btnDelete_Click"/>`
```

my question is, why my multiple delete still wont work? whats wrong with my code? anyone pls help..

Comment: Why the [tag:asp-classic] tag?

Comment: Do you get any exception when you try to delete multiple rows ?

Comment: theres no any exception, but dunno why, multiple del wont work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Protected Sub btnDelete_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
  For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
     Dim checkbox As CheckBox = CType(row.FindControl("chkdelete"), CheckBox)
        If checkbox.Checked Then
           Dim ID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys(row.RowIndex).Value)
             Delete(ID)
        End If

  Next row 

End Sub

Public Function Delete(ByRef ID as Integer)
' Your Connection Coding comes here

  SqlDataSource1.DeleteParameters("ID").DefaultValue = ID.ToString()
    SqlDataSource1.Delete()
End Function
```

Try This Way..!!